# .NET OpenApi dynamic data types of class property

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, openapi

Let's say I have a class I would like to be returned by API:

```
public class MyClass
{
    ...
    public object someObject { get; set; }
    ...

    public MyClass(object someObject)
    {
        this.someObject = someObject;
    }
}
```

And as **someObject** property in this class I would like to return one or another class:

```
public class CustomClass1
{
    ...
}

public class CustomClass2
{
    ...
}
```

My API method in controller looks something like this:

```
[HttpGet()]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(MyClass), 200)]
public async Task<IActionResult> ApiMethod([Required] string input)
{
    if (...)
        return new OkObjectResult(new MyClass(new class CustomClass1());
    else
        return new OkObjectResult(new MyClass(new class CustomClass2());
}
```

But in Swagger models **CustomClass1** and **CustomClass2** are not specified and **MyClass**'s property **someObject** is empty and looks like this: **{}**. Is there any way to tell OpenApi to "index" those classes as models and specify that one or another type will be returned? Possibly some alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would  the below codes meet your requirement?

```
public class Myclass
    {
        // Contains all property of Entity1/Entity2
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
        public string Prop3 { get; set; }
        public string Prop4 { get; set; }


    }


    public class Entity1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Entity2
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Prop3 { get; set; }
        public string Prop4 { get; set; }
    }
```

Api:

```
[HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(Myclass))]
        
        public ActionResult<Myclass> GetUserEntity(int id)
        {
            object entity;
            if (somecondition)
            {
                 entity = new Entity1() { Id = 1, Prop1 = "prop1", Prop2 = "prop2" };


            }

            else
            {
                entity = new Entity2() { Id = 2, Prop3 = "prop3", Prop4 = "prop4" };
            }

            var jsonstr = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(entity);

            var target = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Myclass>(jsonstr);


            return Ok(target);
            
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It would probably be the easiest solution.